# How can I use Shearing and Loopsliding correctly?

Tags: modeling

I am following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzA5fOIq8Qw) about modelling a chair, when Shearing and Loopsliding come up at 12 min. It´s recommended to hold down alt or click C in order to activate the loopslide effect of a sheared mesh. I basicly selected two vertecies (one on each side) at the edge of the mesh and want to move the vertecies higher along the face, but the shortcuts alt or c won´t work.[image: shearing]

I think it makes sense to use G before every other shortcut, but that didn´t help either.
Is there another way for this? Here´s the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/1tez5qwvzopn3xk/soborg.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

You just have to doubletap  <kbd>G</kbd> first of all.